# ExpandableListView Parents (Groups) Fill Vertical Space

Tags: android

I have an expandable list view as viz.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Activity Main UI -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkGrey"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Reusable Main Toolbar -->
        <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_sys_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            tools:ignore="UnknownIdInLayout">
        </ExpandableListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Reusable Main Toolbar -->
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the XML information for the group is viz.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_flat_black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_sys_gr_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, contrary to my belief, the groups only fill a portion of the screen space when un-expanded as viz.

[image: expandable list view blank]

So, I want the expandable list view groups (or parents) to fill the available space in the UI, but even after multiple tries I failed to achieve this. How can this be done?

Here is the adapter, just in case:

```
public class SystemDetailsAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<DeviceInfoGroup> groups;

    public SystemDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DeviceInfoGroup> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<DeviceInfoChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
                .getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DeviceInfoChild child = (DeviceInfoChild) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (layoutInflater != null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.system_info_row, null);
            }
        }

        TextView title = null;
        if (convertView != null) {
            title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_title);
        }

        TextView subtitle = null;
        if (convertView != null) {
            subtitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_subtitle);
        }

        ImageView sideIcon = null;
        if (convertView != null) {
            sideIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_img_left);
        }

        if (title != null) {
            title.setText(child.getTitle());
        }
        if (subtitle != null) {
            subtitle.setText(child.getSubtitle());
        }
        if (sideIcon != null) {
            sideIcon.setImageResource(child.getImage());
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<DeviceInfoChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
                .getItems();

        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DeviceInfoGroup group = (DeviceInfoGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (inf != null) {
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.system_info_group, null);
            }
        }
        TextView tv = null;
        if (convertView != null) {
            tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_sys_gr_header);
        }
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.setText(group.getName());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to do it as follows:

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight() / 7));
```

Comment: Why divided by seven?

Comment: @nasch I don't remember exactly, but that's what gave the most optimal result. (6 + 1)